# Changing CSS attributes

Tags: javascript

I use Waypoints.js (http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/waypoint/ -- no-framework dependency).

Now I want to change CSS attributes on waypoints. What would be the best way to handle my code in a modular way?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header" id="header"></div>
<button class="menu"></button>
```

**JS:**

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({

    element: document.getElementById('direction-waypoint'),
    handler: function(direction) {
        if (direction == 'down') {
            document.getElementById("header").setAttribute("style", "position: fixed;");
            document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundColor = "white";
            document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("li")[0].setAttribute("style", "background-color: #999;");
            document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("li")[1].setAttribute("style", "background-color: #999;");
            document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("li")[2].setAttribute("style", "background-color: #999;");

        } else {
            document.getElementById("header").setAttribute("style", "position: absolute;");
            document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("li")[0].setAttribute("style", "background-color: default;");
            document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("li")[1].setAttribute("style", "background-color: default;");
            document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("li")[2].setAttribute("style", "background-color: default;");

        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Why not add and remove classes instead? Setting static styles in JavaScript is usually bad practice.

Comment: You gave to assign the value to the style.

Comment: @Ryan Ok, then I don't even need a if statement anymore, right?

Comment: @andremcgruder I'm lost right now lol. I also use CSS classes on the same elements which have the ids..

Comment: All JS is vanilla JS, except for a dwindling group of old-timers still using the obsolete technology called jQuery. On Stack Overflow, if you say "JavaScript", the assumption--without having to say so explicitly--is that you **don't** want a jQuery solution. You can assume a jQuery solution is desired or permitted only if the question is specifically tagged jQuery7.

Answer (score -1):

You do it like this.

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({

    element: document.getElementById('direction-waypoint'),
    handler: function(direction) {

    var headerElem = document.getElementById("header"),
    menuElem = document.getElementById("menu");

        if (direction == 'down') {
            )

    headerElem.style.position = 'fixed';
    headerElem.style.background-color = 'white';

    menuElem.children[0].style.background-color = '#999';
     menuElem.children[1].style.background-color = '#999';
            menuElem.children[2].style.background-color =  '#999';

        } else {

     headerElem.style.position = 'absolute';

     menuElem.children[0].style.background-color = '';
     menuElem.children[1].style.background-color = '';
    menuElem.children[2].style.background-color = '';

        }
    }

});
```

If you do a console.dir you can see all of the elements properties. It a good way to evaluate things when your using vanilla JavaScript.

```
var headerElem = document.getElementById("header");

console.dir(headerElem);
```

Comment: Not familiar with Waypoints but if this is plain JS then your `background-color` should be `backgroundColor`.

Comment: `background-color` isn’t valid syntax and I’m not sure how this is better than what was already in the question.